# Directory Services with OpenLDAP

Tags: macos, ldap, directory-utility

I have an OpenLDAP instance running on Amazon AWS.  I've got a few users and groups set up, I'm able to use ldapsearch from my macbook to bind and search the server.  I would like was trying to add my OpenLDAP server as a node in my Directory Services, and I provided all the necessary information, but it will not connect giving the oh so informative

```
Connection failed to node 
'/LDAPv3/XX.XXX.XXX.X'  <--IP address hidden for security purposes
(2100)
```

I've tried to debug this with dcsl (granted I just learned what it was today) and I can see the new node

```
$ dscl
Entering interactive mode... (type "help" for commands)
 > ls /LDAPv3/
XX.XXX.XXX.X
```

but if try to do anything with the node (cd, list, read, etc.), I get this:

```
Invalid Path
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName)
```

why is the nodename unknown? what am i doing wrong